# OPC UA tags collecting (OPCFoundation NETStandard library, code correction)

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, client-certificates, opc-ua

## Task

The final project in question is worker app (runtime: net6.0, target OS: Windows Server 2012R2) intended to be used as Windows Service to gather data from KEPServer, which is a proxy for internal system, using OPC UA protocol.

## OPC UA server settings

Supported security policies:

1. Basic256Sha256: Sign; Sign and Encrypt.
2. Basic256: Sign; Sign and Encrypt.
3. Basic128Rsa15: Sign; Sign and Encrypt.

Server admin assured me that no certificates with private keys are used. Extension used are of `.der` type.

## My configuration

Sensitive data has been substituted by dummy stub such as 'port', 'ip' due to security considerations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationConfiguration
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:ua="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd"
  xmlns="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/SDK/Configuration.xsd"
>
  <ApplicationName>OPCFoundationConsoleClient</ApplicationName>
  <ApplicationUri>urn:localhost:OPCFoundationConsoleClient</ApplicationUri>
  <ApplicationType>Client_1</ApplicationType>
  
  <SecurityConfiguration>

    <ApplicationCertificate>
      <StoreType>Directory</StoreType>
      <StorePath>%LocalFolder%/CertificateStores/pki/own</StorePath>
      <SubjectName>CN=MY_CLIENT, C=Country, S=City, O=organization, DC=opc.tcp://ip:port</SubjectName>
      <!--<Thumbprint>Some hash</Thumbprint>-->
    </ApplicationCertificate>

    <TrustedIssuerCertificates>
      <StoreType>Directory</StoreType>
      <StorePath>%LocalFolder%/CertificateStores/pki/issuer</StorePath>
    </TrustedIssuerCertificates>

    <TrustedPeerCertificates>
      <StoreType>Directory</StoreType>
      <StorePath>%LocalFolder%/CertificateStores/pki/trusted</StorePath>
    </TrustedPeerCertificates>

    <RejectedCertificateStore>
      <StoreType>Directory</StoreType>
      <StorePath>%LocalFolder%/CertificateStores/pki/rejected</StorePath>
    </RejectedCertificateStore>

    <AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates>false</AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates>

  </SecurityConfiguration>
  
  <TransportConfigurations></TransportConfigurations>
  
  <TransportQuotas>
    <OperationTimeout>120000</OperationTimeout>
    <MaxStringLength>4194304</MaxStringLength>
    <MaxByteStringLength>4194304</MaxByteStringLength>
    <MaxArrayLength>65535</MaxArrayLength>
    <MaxMessageSize>4194304</MaxMessageSize>
    <MaxBufferSize>65535</MaxBufferSize>
    <ChannelLifetime>300000</ChannelLifetime>
    <SecurityTokenLifetime>3600000</SecurityTokenLifetime>
  </TransportQuotas>

  <ClientConfiguration>
    <DefaultSessionTimeout>60000</DefaultSessionTimeout>
    
    <WellKnownDiscoveryUrls>
      <ua:String>opc.tcp://{0}:port</ua:String>
    </WellKnownDiscoveryUrls>
   
    <DiscoveryServers></DiscoveryServers>
    <MinSubscriptionLifetime>10000</MinSubscriptionLifetime>

    <OperationLimits>
      <MaxNodesPerRead>2500</MaxNodesPerRead>
      <MaxNodesPerHistoryReadData>1000</MaxNodesPerHistoryReadData>
      <MaxNodesPerHistoryReadEvents>1000</MaxNodesPerHistoryReadEvents>
      <MaxNodesPerWrite>2500</MaxNodesPerWrite>
      <MaxNodesPerHistoryUpdateData>1000</MaxNodesPerHistoryUpdateData>
      <MaxNodesPerHistoryUpdateEvents>1000</MaxNodesPerHistoryUpdateEvents>
      <MaxNodesPerMethodCall>2500</MaxNodesPerMethodCall>
      <MaxNodesPerBrowse>2500</MaxNodesPerBrowse>
      <MaxNodesPerRegisterNodes>2500</MaxNodesPerRegisterNodes>
      <MaxNodesPerTranslateBrowsePathsToNodeIds>2500</MaxNodesPerTranslateBrowsePathsToNodeIds>
      <MaxNodesPerNodeManagement>2500</MaxNodesPerNodeManagement>
      <MaxMonitoredItemsPerCall>2500</MaxMonitoredItemsPerCall>
    </OperationLimits>

  </ClientConfiguration>
  
</ApplicationConfiguration>
```

So far so good. The subject is set. Paths to storage folders are set. I also added KEPServer's certificate to *.CertificatesStores/pki/issuer/certs*. App certificate has been passed to server admin to be added to the trusted list. He also said no errors arose during PHD reinitialization.

## My code sample

After having taken a look at "ConsoleReferenceClient" from UA-.NETStandard-Samples (as it seems the most appropriate to me) repo, I've dropped the following lines of code:

```
using System.Text.Json;
using Opc.Ua;
using Opc.Ua.Client;
using Opc.Ua.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Models;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

const string tagsDataSettingsName = "tagsDataSettings.json"; // tags' ID list and other relevant settings

try {
 /* configuration handling logic */
  var configuration = await application.LoadApplicationConfiguration(silent: false); 
  var haveAppCertificate = await application.CheckApplicationInstanceCertificate(true, 2048);
  if (!haveAppCertificate) {
    throw new Exception("Application certificate isn't found."); 
  } 
  var endpointDescription = CoreClientUtils.SelectEndpoint(configuration, tds.Host.Address, true); // tds is a custom settings variable
  endpointDescription.SecurityMode = (MessageSecurityMode)tds.Host.SecurityMode;
  endpointDescription.SecurityPolicyUri = tds.Host.SecurityPolicyUri;  
  var endpointConfiguration = EndpointConfiguration.Create(configuration);  
  ConfiguredEndpoint endpoint = new(null, endpointDescription, endpointConfiguration); 
  var certificate = configuration.SecurityConfiguration.ApplicationCertificate.Certificate;
  using (var session = await TraceableSessionFactory.Instance.CreateAsync(configuration: configuration, endpoint: endpoint, updateBeforeConnect: true, checkDomain: false, sessionName: "", sessionTimeout: 60000, identity: new UserIdentity(certificate), preferredLocales: null)) {
    if (session!.Connected) {
      var readValues = tds.TagGroups?.Aggregate(new ReadValueIdCollection(), 
        (final, current) => {
          Array.ForEach(current.Tags!, 
            id => {
              var tag = new ReadValueId() 
              { 
                NodeId = new NodeId(id), 
                AttributeId = Attributes.Value 
              };
              final.Add(tag);
             });
          return final;
        });
      var response = await session.ReadAsync(null, 0, TimestampsToReturn.Both, readValues, CancellationToken.None);
      var formattedData = response.Results.Aggregate("", 
        (final, current) => { 
          var tagData = $"[{current.SourceTimestamp}]: status code: {current.StatusCode}; value: {current.Value}";
          final = (final == "") ? $"{tagData}" : $"{final}\n{tagData}"; 
          return final;
        });
      Console.WriteLine(formattedData);
      await session!.CloseAsync();
    }
  }
  Console.ReadKey();
} catch (AggregateException agrErr) {
  foreach (var ie in agrErr.InnerExceptions) {
    Console.WriteLine($"AggregatedException.InnerExceptions error: {ie.Message}"); 
  }
  Console.ReadKey();
} catch (Exception err) {
  Console.WriteLine($"Error: {err.Message}"); 
  Console.ReadKey();
}
var i = 2;
while (i > 0) {
  Console.WriteLine($"The application shuts down in {i} s");
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  i--;
}
```

`tds` object is of record type and used for tags IDs (*ns=2;s=Namespace.Device.TagName*) storage as well as server's address. It also contains security policy URL and security mode type. This is my custom configuration of `.json` format.

## Issue description

When I deploy and start my app at a production server I get an error: `Endpoint doesn't support the user identity type provided`. Application certificates are created: `.der` in *own* subfolder and `.pfx` - *private*. As far as I understand, the message is straightforward: server doesn't want to allow connection.

I tried to test connection with UaExpert program, but when I set *Authentication Settings => Certificate*, I get error that says X509 certificate private key isn't found. The program also doesn't allow to use generated `.pfx` certificate. Only `.pem` is allowed in file browser. So it gave me no significant results. When chosing policy, I can use the mentioned above in *Server settings* block only.

`certificate.PrivateKey` returns `true`, but as per requirements of the admin I'm not allowed to use it.

`certificate.GetHashString()` returns the correct hash. I suppose app tries to use `.pfx` certificate, but how can I make use regular `.der` one?

What should I do? Convert `.der` to `.pem`? `.pfx` is keys storage, so I can extract key from it somehow? I wish there was more detailed specification.

So, I can sum up the following:

1. How to get opened connection using such input parameters?
2. How to set certificate expiration date, if it's possible at all? Some subject attributes (I haven't found relative tips)? Will I be pushed to pass new certificate to admin every following year (by default, it's 1 year from creation date)?
3. When I try to format the output of server response, I don't see any ID property. How could I add tag ID data to response string? How to distinguish tag values, if they are to be written to DB?

P.S. I've come across some examples on this site, but they don't use certificates (anonymous identity) and they use items monitoring, whereas I need to make session by interval (timer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confusing the OPC UA *application* authentication (which is always done with the certificates) with the *user* authentication, which is a different concept. Study the OPC UA specs to get understanding of these. *User* authentication can be anonymous, username/password, or also (less commonly) a certificate.

You have improperly passed the OPC UA *application* certificate in the UserIdentity to the session. And, you are trying to the same with the steps you described with UaExpert. Not only this is the wrong certificate, but to my knowledge, KepServer does not support X509 certificates for *user* authentication at all. You need to use anonymous, or username/password. And,
AFAIK, KepServer does not not allow anonymous *user* connections by default.

Therefore, in order to resolve your issue, you need to either

1. Create a UserIdentity with proper username and password, and *not* a certificate, and pass it to the session creation call, OR
2. Allow anonymous user connection in KepServer (Edit -> Properties; OPC UA -> Allow anonymouse login), and then create an empty (anonymous) UserIdentity and pass it to the session creation call.

One you get the connection, other unrelated questions you have mentioned should be posted as separate questions on SO.

Comment: That's it! Administrator just provided me with login and password. As for certificate, `CreateAsync` method accepts X509 Certificate, so it was the point that confused me. Thank you, so much.